# -[UICIColor colorSpaceName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface

I am creating several classes for theme-ing support in my iOS 5 app. My themes are stored in plist and I load them up in a Theme object, which I use in my app to initialize various controls. I store the colors as strings in my theme and then I use this code to convert them to UIColor:

```
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithCIColor:[CIColor colorWithString:@"0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0"]];
```

This works fine for most controls, however when I try to set the tint color of the navigation bar as such:

```
//navigation bar
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:color];
```

I get this exception:

```
-[UICIColor colorSpaceName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

When I initialize the color without using CIColor e.g. like this:

```
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:color];
```

All works great.

Any clues what is causing this? I could not find much info about UICIColor, but I am guessing since UIColor is only a wrapper on top of CGColor or CIColor there are implementation differences.

Comment: Interesting question. I wonder, do you get the same result if you use UIColor* color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithCIColor:[CIColor colorWithString:@"0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0"]];?

Comment: have u added CoreImage Framework and check what @Darren suggested. As its working fine for me..

Comment: Yes I have CI included in the project and I also tried to allocate it explicitly. It does work for any other use other than when I want to set the navbar color... go figure.

Comment: I decided to just parse the string and create RGB components. This works and there is no need to add CI.

Comment: I have the same problem since I upgraded to xcode 4.5 . Is it also your case ?

Comment: This appears to be a bug. You should file a bug report at: [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: @Tobi thanks for the suggestions I filed a bug report with them.

Answer (score 2):

See [Strange crash when I try to access to uibutton's titleLabel property (xcode 4.5 and IOS sdk 6.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586834/strange-crash-when-i-try-to-access-to-uibuttons-titlelabel-property-xcode-4-5)

I found a workaround : before using my colorWithCIColor, I made a copy of it with :

```
newcolor = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:newcolor.CGColor];
```

and it solves the crash. Strange, anyway

Comment: I have faced same problem today and this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with

```
[UIColor colorWithCIColor:[CIColor colorWithString:color]];
```

Although I looked for an elegant fix for this, in the end I settled with a solution that stopped the problem and enabled my app to continue exactly as before.

My color string was in the same format as yours:

```
"0.5 0.7 0.2 0.75"
```

I found the easiest way to fix it was just to do the following:

```
NSArray * colorParts = [color componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];

CGFloat red = [[colorParts objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
CGFloat green = [[colorParts objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
CGFloat blue = [[colorParts objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
CGFloat alpha = [[colorParts objectAtIndex:3] floatValue];

UIColor * newColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
```

Manually splitting out each value and then putting then into the colorWithRed: code.

It means you can keep your color string but get rid of the problematic colorWithString code which is causing all the crashes.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

`UIColor` define in `iOS 2.0` ,because of `[UIColor colorWithCIColor]` convert to `iOS5.0`, I think that apple convert error, you can using below code:

```
    CIColor *ci_ = [CIColor colorWithString:colorString];
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:ci_.red green:ci_.green blue:ci_.blue alpha:ci_.alpha];
    // UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithCIColor:[CIColor colorWithString:colorString]];
```

Comment: This makes no sense at all.

Comment: yeah, this whole thing doesn't make sense but using this solution solved my app crash. I prefer this solution versus the one where you manually parse the colorString though.