# Strange crash when I try to access to uibutton's titleLabel property (xcode 4.5 and IOS sdk 6.0) 

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, unrecognized-selector

I found another annoying bug with xcode 4.5 and sdk 6.0 : 
when I run the following code :

```
UIColor *newcolor = [UIColor colorWithCIColor:[CIColor colorWithString:@"1 1 1 1"]];
[button setTitleColor:newcolor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UILabel *lbl = selectedbutton.titleLabel;
```

It always fail with the error :

```
-[UICIColor colorSpaceName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa9864f0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICIColor colorSpaceName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa9864f0'
*** First throw call stack: [...] 
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see the symbols on the stack when this happens in order to find out what is causing that method to be called.  Does it work if you explicitly use float values in your string: @"1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0" (or @"1.0 1.0 1.0" with default alpha)?

Comment: no, doesn't work either. same error. My real value are floats, I put integer in the sample to illustrate. I think it has something to do with de CIColor colorspace profile.

Comment: There's certainly something odd going on because pasting your code for color creation into a test project and linking to the Core Image framework doesn't give me any error.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround : 
before using my colorWithCIColor, I made a copy of it with :

```
newcolor = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:newcolor.CGColor];
```

and it solves the crash. 
Strange, anyway

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation as you where I had a string of the constituent values of the RGB UIColor

Although using CIColor colorWithString: is much more compact to get rid of the error I converted it manually:

```
NSArray * colorParts = [color componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];

CGFloat red = [[colorParts objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
CGFloat green = [[colorParts objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
CGFloat blue = [[colorParts objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
CGFloat alpha = [[colorParts objectAtIndex:3] floatValue];

UIColor * newColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];

[button setTitleColor:newcolor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This certainly isn't the most elegant way of doing it but is a good fix if this suddenly becomes an issue after an update.